# Is there an enumeration for system error codes in .Net framework?

Tags: .net, pinvoke

I have a library function that returns GetLastError codes ([things like these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I need to compare them with specific errors, like `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. However I don't feel comfortable to define the constants myself. So the question is, is there a predefined enumeration for this purpose?

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WINERROR.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you'll have to make your own.

Answer (score 6):

I published a [NuGet package](https://github.com/mkropat/BetterWin32Errors/) for this:

```
Install-Package BetterWin32Errors
```

First add a using for the library:

```
using BetterWin32Errors;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
if (!SomeWin32ApiCall(...))
{
    var error = Win32Exception.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (error == Win32Error.ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        // ...do something...
    }
    else if (error == Win32Error.ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        // ...do something else...
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }
}
```

See [the site](https://github.com/mkropat/BetterWin32Errors/) for more examples of how to use the library.

Comment: Wow! That's such a lifesaver! I'm surprised it took 15 years for someone to put together something so straightforward for handling Win32 error codes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx added by katmassage to your own class SystemErrorCodes.
It contains the codes from 0 to 499. This is a good starter. If someone already has a class containing also all the codes his code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Win32Exception class can be used for this.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Setting the system Date and Time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateAndTime">The date and time settings</param>
    /// <returns>Operation success</returns>
    public static bool SetSystemTimeAndDate(DateTime dateAndTime)
    {
        var newDateAndTime = new Win32SystemTimeStruct(dateAndTime);

        var ret = Win32ApiStub.SetSystemTime(ref newDateAndTime);
        if(!ret)
            ThrowExceptionForHr(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        return ret;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function checks an error code and throws a nice exception if the code is signifying an error.
    /// Do not confuse this with <see cref="Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR"/> which gets error information out of the context of the current thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nativeErrorCode">The HRESULT error code</param>
    public static void ThrowExceptionForHr(int nativeErrorCode)
    {
        if (nativeErrorCode != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(nativeErrorCode);
    }
```

Comment: Also  see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--0-499- and FormatMessage

Answer (score 0):

There is class published at pinvoke. I haven't tried to post the 12.000 lines here.

Download: [WINERROR](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WINERROR.html)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Microsoft.Win32.Interop
{
    public class ResultWin32
    {
        public static string GetErrorName(int result)
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(ResultWin32).GetFields();
            foreach (FieldInfo fi in fields)
                if ((int)fi.GetValue(null) == result)
                    return fi.Name;
            return String.Empty;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The operation completed successfully.
        /// </summary>
        public const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// Incorrect function.
        /// </summary>
        public const int ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION = 1;
        /// <summary>
        /// The system cannot find the file specified.
        /// </summary>
        public const int ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 2;
        /// <summary>
        /// The system cannot find the path specified.
        /// </summary>



        // !! Don't use this cutout
        // get the whole file at: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WINERROR.html



        public const int COMADMIN_E_SAFERINVALID = (int)(0x80110822 - 0x100000000);
        /// <summary>
        /// The specified user cannot write to the system registry
        /// </summary>
        public const int COMADMIN_E_REGISTRY_ACCESSDENIED = (int)(0x80110823 - 0x100000000);
        /// <summary>
        /// No information avialable.
        /// </summary>
        public const int COMADMIN_E_PARTITIONS_DISABLED = (int)(0x80110824 - 0x100000000);
        /// <summary>
        /// Failed to open a file.
        /// </summary>
        public const int NS_E_FILE_OPEN_FAILED = (int)(0xC00D001DL - 0x100000000);

        public static bool Succeeded(int result)
        {
            return result >= 0;
        }

        public static bool Failed(int result)
        {
            return result < 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer originally aims the errors described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d), but seems like yours are a subset of those.

All the answers here talk about having to do the work manually. I just did that (scraped the aforementioned link and generated an enum class with those values).

But - to my despair - I figured out that you can simply do `throw new Win32Exception(errorCode)` and you get the matching error message text.

Read about [Win32Exception here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception?view=net-5.0).